# Advanced sorting criteria for a list of nested tuples

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have a list of nested tuples of the form:

```
[(a, (b, c)), ...]
```

Now I would like to pick the element which maximizes *a* while minimizing *b* and *c* at the same time. For example in

```
[(7, (5, 1)), (7, (4, 1)), (6, (3, 1))]
```

the winner should be

```
(7, (4, 1))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Given `(7,(4,1))` and `(7,(3,2))`, which one wins?

Comment: Good question. (7,(3,2)) wins.

Comment: let me guess exactly what you're prioritizing in your sort: The biggest `a`, then the smallest `b`, then the smallest `c`. Is that right?

Comment: @eksortso: Yes that is right. I should have made this clear in the question, sorry. However, in my data c tends to be very small, so it can actually be ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my understanding, you want to sort decreasingly by a, and ascendingly by b, then by c. If that's right, you can do it like so:

```
>>> l=[(7, (5, 1)), (7, (4, 1)), (6, (3, 2)), (6, (3, 1))]
>>> sorted(l, key = lambda x: (-x[0], x[1]))
[(7, (4, 1)), (7, (5, 1)), (6, (3, 1)), (6, (3, 2))]
```

Picking the "winner" would be as simple as picking the first element.

If b and c should be summed up, it would simply be `sum(x[1])` instead of `x[1]` in my example.

My key function returns a tuple because Python correctly sorts tuples containing multiple elements:

```
>>> sorted([(1,2), (1,1), (1,-1), (0,5)])
[(0, 5), (1, -1), (1, 1), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: `max` has `key` parameter, so there is no need to create an intermediate list. The signs of course would need to be reversed.

Comment: @SilentGhost: Of course the `max` function is a good idea here. I wanted to point out that, depending on the problem (or homework) the OP is trying to solve, it might be necessary to pick multiple items. Therefore, a presorted list would be better.

Comment: It is actually a real problem and no homework. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> max(lst, key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1][0], -x[1][1]))
(7, (4, 1))
```